# Scalate sbt 0.11.0 plugin help

Tags: scala, pug, scalate, scalatra

I'm developing a Scalatra web app with Scalate Jade and using sbt 0.11.0

I've been packaging the web app with "com.github.siasia" %% "xsbt-web-plugin" % "0.1.2".

I've also been experimenting with "com.zentrope" %% "xsbt-scalate-precompile-plugin" % "1.6" to compile the Jade files.

Unfortunately if I use the xsbt-web-plugin to package my war it clears the target directory from any precompiled Scalate files.

What is the best way to package a war with precompiled Scalate files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Keith Irwin, the author of [xsbt-scalate-precompile-plugin](https://github.com/zentrope/xsbt-scalate-precompile-plugin), I now have a solution to my problem.

My Jade/Scalate files are in webapp/WEB-INF/template and webapp/WEB-INF/scalate/layouts directories.

I'm using the xsbt-web-plugin and xsbt-scalate-precompile-plugin sbt plugins.

- xsbt-web-plugin provides me with the package-war command.
- xsbt-scalate-precompile-plugin pre-compiles my Jade files.

In my plugins.sbt file.

```
resolvers += "Web plugin repo" at "http://siasia.github.com/maven2"    
addSbtPlugin("com.github.siasia" %% "xsbt-web-plugin" % "0.1.2")

resolvers += "zentrope" at "http://zentrope.com/maven"    
addSbtPlugin("com.zentrope" %% "xsbt-scalate-precompile-plugin" % "1.7")
```

In my build.scala file.

```
import WebPlugin._
import Keys._
import com.zentrope.ScalatePlugin._

...

// WebApp Settings
val webAppSettings = Seq(
  jettyPort := 8083,
  jettyContext := "/MyWebApp"
)

// Scalate Compile Settings
val scalateCompileSettings = scalateTemplateSettings ++ Seq(
  scalateTemplateDirectories in Compile <<= (scalateTemplateDirectories in Compile, baseDirectory) {
    (dirs, basedir) => dirs ++ Seq(new File(basedir, "/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/template"),
      new File(basedir, "/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/scalate/layouts"))
  }
)

...

lazy val MyWebApp =
    Project("MyWebApp", file("MyWebApp"), settings = shared ++ webAppSettings ++ scalateCompileSettings ++ Seq(
      resolvers ++= Seq(sonatypeNexusReleases, scalaToolsNexus, novusRels, scalaToolsSnapshots),
      libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
        scalatra,
        scalate,
        ...
      )
    ))
```

The 1.7 version of Keiths' plugin allows for the setting of specific template directories which is what I really needed.  The only caveat is that I must do a clean right before I call package-war or my compiled Jade files get removed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand you here. Anything that's source should be in `src`. One should never put anything in `target`. Resources would naturally go into `src/main/resources`. So, are these "precompiled" files something that is being automatically generated, or should they have been in the resources directory?